# Django-profile and django-registration get started

Tags: python, django

I've installed Django-registration succesfully [(form this tutorial)](http://devdoodles.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/user-authentication-with-django-registration/).

So now I have a Django project "loginSystem", with in this map *urls.py, settings.py, manage.py and _init_.py*, so there is no app created but it works. The registration-folder is installed in my python-packages folder.

No I want to give to each users a unique profile, so I'll do [this manual for django-profiles](http://birdhouse.org/blog/2009/06/27/django-profiles/). The profiles folder is also installed in my python-packages folder.

But what do I have to create now to follow and start this django-profiles manual?
Because they start speaking about a "/profiles/edit"-folder...
So do I have to work in the dist-packages/profiles folder, or in my project-folder (without app)?

Thanks a lot, it asked me already a lot of time without result...

Comment: I believe /profiles/edit/ is a url not a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see there they are talking about a `/profiles/edit/` folder. The only thing you have to do is creating a `/profiles/` folder in your `TEMPLATE_DIR` and put an `edit_profile.html` template there. Then you still need to hock up the url configuration to serve the edit view of the profiles app (they suggest a url somewhere like `/profiles/edit/`) and then you are good to go. Its basically the same as for django-registration except django-registration already create the url configuration for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
So I don't need to create a new app? (I'm currently working further in  my project created for the django-registration)

Comment: @Francis Michels, it's not a new app, just a folder with your *.html templates for profiles.

Comment: Yes, I know it, but I mean generally; Do I need to create a new app to make the django-profiles work?

"First, you need to create a custom ModelForm based on your Profile model. If you don’t already have a forms.py in your app, create one, then add something like:"
=> But I'm working only in a project...

Comment: You need to create model for your profile, and yes...if you want to edit the profile you need to `ModelForm` based on your profile model. But its not required to create a new app for this. Simply but the model and form in one of your existing apps where you think it fits best (usually in your main app gluing everything together).